# How to add subscription for the "greater than or equal to " sign in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex

I'm trying to use an expression that has a subscripted greater than or equal sign as the facet_grid title for my plot. The latex version of the expression goes like

[image]   .

First I used the following code to have the greater than or equal to sign in the expressions, which can be correctly parsed and displayed by the `facet_grid` function.

`data$type <- factor(data$type, levels = c('A holds', "A doesn't hold"),labels = c(expression(S>=T), expression(S<=T)))`.

But when I try to add the subscription `A` with code `expression(S>=[A]T)`, R keeps reporting me an error

> Unexpected token '['
> .

Any suggestions on how to incorporate the subscription as the latex above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an invisible placeholder before `[A]` to have a legal expression - you can use `phantom` for this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

data$type <- factor(data$type, levels = c('A holds', "A doesn't hold"),
                    labels = c(expression(S >=phantom(0)[A]~T), 
                               expression(S <= phantom(0)[A]~T)))

ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(.~type, labeller = label_parsed) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 20))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Data**

```r
data <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10, 2), y = rnorm(20),
                   type = rep(c('A holds', "A doesn't hold"), each = 10))
```